# argument order in cygwin gcc 4.3 matters when linking with glib-2.0

Tags: gcc, autoconf, arguments

I am trying to compile code that works on os x and linux using cygwin.  However, I am finding that the argument order to gcc gives unanticipated results.

For example, the following fails:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -fgnu89-inline -fno-leading-underscore -o nb-learn.exe nb-learn.c
```

but the following works:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -fno-leading-underscore -o nb-learn.exe nb-learn.c -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv
```

Can someone explains how this works?  Also, are there techniques or code I can look at for getting autoconf to change the argument order depending on the platform?

Here are the first two lines of the error message:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/aischein/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9MvUsf.o:nb-learn.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `_g_hash_table_size'
/cygdrive/c/Users/aischein/AppData/Local/Temp/cc9MvUsf.o:nb-learn.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `_g_hash_table_get_keys'
```

Thanks,

SetJmp 
(gcc 4.3.4)

Comment: What is the output of `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 --cflags glib-2.0`?

Comment: Laurynas, the output is:

`-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv`

Comment: @SetJmp and what is the error message in the first case?

Comment: @Laurynas: I have added some of the error message (the remaining error messages are similar symbol errors).  Also, I replaced the `pkg-config` call with more explicit values.

Comment: Why do you need `-fno-leading-underscore`

Comment: @Artyom, after checking I find that that -fno-leading-underscore is not necessary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC documentation says:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Libraries-1251)

> `-l`*library*
>
> `-l` *library*
>
> Search the library named *library* when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified.
>
> Thus, ``foo.o -lz bar.o`' searches library ``z`' after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in ``z`', those functions may not be loaded.

`-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` options are useful sometimes for avoiding such problems.

All this isn't a problem if you use only shared libraries.

Comment: To answer the second part of the question (autoconf integration), the LIBS variable is placed after source files in the autoconf-generated Makefiles.