# Undefined symbols when linking with g++? How do I solve this?

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

my make file:

```
all: hPif clean

hPif : src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o src/Config.o
    g++ src/Config.o src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o  -lfann -L/usr/local/lib -o hPif

Config.o : src/Config.cpp src/Config.h
    g++ -c src/Config.cpp

hashes.o : src/hashes.cpp src/hashes.h
    g++ -c src/hashes.cpp

fann_utils.o: src/fann_utils.cpp fann_utils.h src/Config.h src/hashes.h
    g++ -c src/fann_utils.cpp 

main.o: src/main.cpp src/Config.h src/main.h src/hashes.h
    g++ -c src/main.cpp

clean: 
    rm -rf src/*o
    rm -rf *o
```

the error I get, upon make:

```
g++ src/Config.o src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o  -lfann -L/usr/local/lib -o hPif
Undefined symbols:
  "Config::NO_FILE_TRAIN", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
  "Config::LEARNING_RATE", referenced from:
      display_help()     in main.o
      train_network_no_file()     in main.o
      train_network()     in main.o
      _main in main.o
.
.
.
```

detail on code layout here: [C++: I have this config class that I want to use between all my CPP files, how do I initialize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514583/c-i-have-this-config-class-that-i-want-to-use-between-all-my-cpp-files-how-do)

EDIT:

the code having issues here: http://pastebin.com/PDmHaDaC

Comment: Order matters with gcc linking related options. See, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/1095298/2509 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/2632505/2509.

Comment: Also, as far as debugging `make` is concerned you can always try the offending command on the command line to see if it is make or your command that is causing the problem.

Comment: @dmckee, I don't understand, what's wrong with my order?

Comment: Hmm, works for me.  I did a small scale experiment and the order of Config.o and main.o does not matter on the link line.

Comment: @quamrana, i'll post a link of th eusage of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer you to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514583/c-i-have-this-config-class-that-i-want-to-use-between-all-my-cpp-files-how-do/5514660#5514660) in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514583/c-i-have-this-config-class-that-i-want-to-use-between-all-my-cpp-files-how-do) where the static variables are properly defined:

Source (Config.cpp):

```
#include "Config.h"

int Config::OUTPUT_TO_FILE = 0;
int Config::NEED_TO_TRAIN = 0;
int Config::NO_FILE_TRAIN = 0;
int Config::NEED_TO_TEST = 0;
```

Note the `Config::` qualification to the variables.

Compare this to your paste bin page: http://pastebin.com/PDmHaDaC

Answer (score 0):

You have just learned from your other question the theory of how to handle these static member variables. Instead of immediately trying to hook them into a large codebase, try getting them to work in a small one; write a `helloWorld` that uses them, just a `main.cpp` that defines these variables, modifies them and prints them out. Once that's working you can move the definition into `Config.cpp`, and once *that's* working you can integrate these variables into your project.

**EDIT:**
Here's the trouble:

```
int NO_FILE_TRAIN = false;
```

should be

```
int Config::NO_FILE_TRAIN = false;
```